# PHP: why do arrays with one element get treated as objects when consuming an ASMX function?

Tags: php, arrays, wsdl, asmx

PHP seems to treat one element arrays as objects when returned from an ASMX web service. This can be problematic for example when using the `count()` function, where the supplied argument may not end up being an array at all. Since PHP 8, `count()` (or `array_search()`) throws an error instead of a warning if the supplied argument is not an array,.

sample wsdl response definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ws_get_audit_detailsResponse xmlns="http://tempurl.org">
      <ws_get_audit_detailsResult>
        <ws_status>int</ws_status>
        <ws_message>string</ws_message>
        <audit_dets>
          <audit_details>
            <audit_date>dateTime</audit_date>
            //some other data
          </audit_details>
          <audit_details>
            <audit_date>dateTime</audit_date>
            //some other data
          </audit_details>
        </audit_dets>
      </ws_get_audit_detailsResult>
    </ws_get_audit_detailsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When using the below code to consume an asmx web service:

```
$wsdl = "www.some_url.com/app/webservice.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient ($wsdl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
$result = $client->{$function_name}($parameters)->{$web_service."Result"};
```

If `$result->audit_dets->audit_details` contains one element, it is treated as a `stdClass` as opposed to an array of `stdClass`.  Meaning i need to write if statements using `'is_array()'` to handle both scenarios.

In C#, this problem doesnt occur when creating a service reference. So why does PHP behave like this and not return an array with one element in it?

Comment: This is probably more to do with the implementation of the interface than PHP.  (AFAIK) There is nothing in PHP that would automatically covert a single element array to an object, but when creating an API, it's easy to do this as some perceive it as a better solution.

Comment: @NigelRen as another user pointed out, i needed to pass `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS ` to the soapclient options